# SQLite Querying - Very slow for large data set

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm currently running a query that looks as such:

```
    Select Name from Location Where Created > (long value of date)
    and 
    Created < (long value of date) and LocationContainer = 'a string'
```

Long value of date meaning milliseconds since Epoch, we use that for storing dates.

I have a index built on `LocationContainer`, Created in that order.

I have a query that returns 1.3 million rows, but it also takes about 40 seconds to run. Is that right? Shouldn't this query be much much faster sinc ethe fields i'm querying on are indexed? What am I missing?

Comment: As far as I remember, SQLite is designed for smaller (few 100k rows maybe?) databases, not as large as this one. Are you sure that storing this much data should be done with this tool? I would more likely suggest Firebird for example.

Comment: SQLite's performance isn't up to par with big db servers, but can handle millions of rows just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the order of your where expressions? I'm by no means an expert, but I believe that expressions in the where clause need to specify columns in the same order they were defined in a composite index. So your query should would turn into something like:

```
SELECT Name FROM Location
WHERE LocationContainer = 'a string'
  AND Created > (long value of date)
  AND Created < (long value of date)
```

Essentially if you have a composite index made of of columns A,B,C. A query in which the where clause specifies columns A,B,C in that order or A,B would make use of the index.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. I believe I have tried this before without a change in results but i will try it again.

Comment: Hmm...what do you get if you run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <YOUR QUERY> at the sqlite prompt? If it returns something like "0|0|TABLE Location WITH INDEX <my_index_name>" it's using the index, but if it just returns the table name without "WITH INDEX ..." then something isn't working right.